# Obtener el ABid de un contacto 'Contacts Framework'

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estoy intentando abrir una conversación de `Whatsapp` desde mi app. Tengo importados mis contactos en core data, he mirado la info que da `Whatsapp` en su web y hace falta añadir el `ABid` del contacto en el URL scheme.

He estado mirando la documentación de `Contacts` en la pagina de [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/) y `CNContact` tiene una constante llamada `CNContactIdentifierKey` pero me devuelve una cadena como esta : `86BA6C28-74E5-4A32-A270-5D18C2DFCD3B`.

Cualquier tipo de ayuda es bienvenida y agradecida.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba pasar ese `CNContactIdentifierKey` con esta URL:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?abid=IDENTIFIER&text=Muak!"];
```

En teoría al abrir esta URL con:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
```

Te debería iniciar una conversación con el contacto correspondiente de la lista de contactos poniendo por defecto el texto.

Comment: Sigue sin abrir la conversación en cuestión pasándole el  `CNContactIdentifierKey ` como ABid. te sigue redirigiendo a la lista de chats recientes.

Answer (score 0):

El esquema de `URL` y `parámetro` de texto se pueden integrar fácilmente con aplicaciones como Centro de Lanzamiento de Pro y Borradores. En el Centro de Lanzamiento Pro, crea una acción que le permite escribir un mensaje en el teclado, el lanzamiento de WhatsApp con su texto ya allí:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%
```

Lee mas información aquí https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: Esta info ya la conocía, entiendo como crear el URL scheme. Mi duda reside en conseguir el ABid unico de cada contacto con el Framework de Contacts